# Java serialization - how many bytes for a character?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm having string objects in Java which I'm serializing. Now I'm wondering about the size of each serialized character in the string.

Is it true that standard english letters (e.g. 'a' or 'G') need only 1 or 2 bytes and special symbols like comma or exclamation mark need 8 bytes?

But how much bytes need a number symbol (0 - 9) in a serialized string?

Edit: I do the serialization in the following way:

```
socket = new Socket(host, port);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
outputStream.writeObject(request);
outputStream.flush();
```

The deserialization is done in a similar way using ObjectInputStream.

The object to serialize (request) contains a field of type String which can be e.g. "aaaa" or "aAaA" or "a0A3a5" etc. (i.e. uper- and lowercase letters and numbers).

Comment: A 'char' in Java is a 16 bit unsigned value. That's two bytes without the sign bit. You could find this out by reading the docs.

Comment: Here is a link to the primitives data types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: You're talking about UTF-8 which is a variable length unicode encoding. Character length depends on the encoding you use to serialize your data. So we can answer if you tell us how you serialize your data.

Comment: @nomoa I have edited my post showing now the serialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use JAVA serialization so it complies to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html.

> The representation of String objects consists of length information
>   followed by the contents of the string encoded in modified UTF-8. The
>   modified UTF-8 encoding is the same as used in the JavaTM Virtual
>   Machine and in the java.io.DataInput and DataOutput interfaces; it
>   differs from standard UTF-8 in the representation of supplementary
>   characters and of the null character. The form of the length
>   information depends on the length of the string in modified UTF-8
>   encoding. If the modified UTF-8 encoding of the given String is less
>   than 65536 bytes in length, the length is written as 2 bytes
>   representing an unsigned 16-bit integer. Starting with the JavaTM 2
>   platform, Standard Edition, v1.3, if the length of the string in
>   modified UTF-8 encoding is 65536 bytes or more, the length is written
>   in 8 bytes representing a signed 64-bit integer. The typecode
>   preceding the String in the serialization stream indicates which
>   format was used to write the String.

String are serialized as UTF-8 so ASCII chars are encoded with 1 byte and as numbers are ASCII yes they are encoded with 1 byte.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 for further information.

Comment: Ofcourse this only applies if the type behind request object rely on default serialization and not custom serialization process for its field.

Comment: Is there a possibility to see how many bytes the serialization of the object in outputStream.writeObject(request); is?

Comment: Not out the box but you could implement a wrapper class on top of OutputStream that will count each byte written. Or if it's just to see/test experiment you can write your data into a ByteArrayOuputStream and then count the resulting byte[] length.

Comment: For the wrapper look at an example here : https://github.com/dougm/jets3t/blob/master/src/org/jets3t/service/io/ProgressMonitoredOutputStream.java . And for ByteArrayOuputStream just write to it instead of your Socket and count ByteArrayOuputStream.toByteArray().length

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectOutputStream is designed to write objects. A char takes about 78 bytes. If you want to write a char as two bytes you can use DataOutputStream writeChar or if you want to use a byte you can write(ch);

Comment: I want to write objects but the object contains a string (among other fields). Thus, I was asking how much byte a char in the string will take in the serialized output of the object. Is it really 78 bytes? So if I'm serializing a object which has a string of 100 chars this would already made 100*78 bytes...

Comment: The first character will use about 78 bytes as you are using the object stream however each additional character will use 1-3 bytes based on it UTF-8 encoding. If you use a generic object encoder it is because you don't particularly care how it is encoded. If you want to make assumptions about what you are encoding and thus control how many bytes are used you have to do more of the work yourself.

Comment: alright. How can I measure the number of bytes written or recevied by a call to writeObject or readObject?

Comment: @user1684118 Write the `ObjectObjectStream` to an `ByteArrayOutputStream` which you call `toByteArray().length` on when finished.